# Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://test.com/artifactory/android-devel/org/gradle/6.8/gradle-6.8-bin.zip'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have one project in android studio, but when i try to compile it, it is showing the next error and not permits to build an apk

> Could not install Gradle distribution from
> 'https://test.com/artifactory/android-devel/org/gradle/6.8/gradle-6.8-bin.zip'.

The gradle configuration is

```
#Thu Feb 27 14:57:19 COT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/
distributionUrl=https\://test.com/artifactory/android-devel/org/gradle/6.8/gradle-6.8-bin.zip
```

The url exists  because i try to load the next https://test.com/artifactory/android-devel/org/gradle/6.8/gradle-6.8-bin.zip, it downloads the zip.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, in case the problem was the next

```
https\://test.com/artifactory/android-devel/org/gradle/6.8/gradle-6.8-bin.zip
```

I removed the \ in the url

https://test.com/artifactory/android-devel/org/gradle/6.8/gradle-6.8-bin.zip